# WKWebView Thread 1: signal SIGABRT when using location

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

I am new to Swift and WKWebView.

I have a WKWebView implemented in my App. I want to show a website in it which uses the location like `https://www.google.com/maps`.

I added `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in `Info.plist`.

When I first open the app there is a prompt which asks for the location.

When I click `Allow` the app crashes with the `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` error.

I checked all my outlets and there is definitely no mistake.

Also the error displays:

`UIAlertView is deprecated and unavailable for UIScene based applications, please use UIAlertController!`

But I'm not explicitly call a `UIAlertView` so I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Get anywhere with this? Camera permissions work but any Location permission crashes the app.

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: I have targeted my app to version 12 of iOS, although deprecated it allows the UIAlertView to pop

Comment: @Soteri any clue on this? My app also gets crash for the same reason.

Comment: Any update on a solution? Same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me too, this sucks.

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectNotAvailableException', reason: 'UIAlertView is deprecated and unavailable for UIScene based applications, please use UIAlertController!'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b98bde __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff503b5b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b98a1c +[NSException raise:format:] + 188
    3   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff466e9463 -[UIAlertView initWithFrame:] + 417
    4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff466e9ad0 -[UIAlertView initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:] + 218
    5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47516acf +[UIAlertView(ViewServiceSupport) _alertViewForWindow:] + 217
    6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff476cdb44 -[UIWebGeolocationPolicyDecider _executeNextChallenge] + 242
    7   WebKit                              0x00007fff2d123a6d _ZN6WebKit43decidePolicyForGeolocationRequestFromOriginEPN7WebCore14SecurityOriginERKN3WTF6StringEPU37objcproto26WebAllowDenyPolicyListener11objc_objectP8UIWindow + 169
    8   WebKit                              0x00007fff2d123641 -[WKGeolocationProviderIOS(WebGeolocationCoreLocationUpdateListener) geolocationAuthorizationGranted] + 603
    9   WebKit                              0x00007fff2d12328d -[WKGeolocationProviderIOS
...
```

Comment: I have targeted my app to version 12 of iOS, although deprecated it allows the UIAlertView to pop

Comment: @johan Have you found any solution for this? I am facing the same error on the latest iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Its funny you don't get this error with the "location always" description. but you never get a location...

I have downgraded my app to target platform "iOS 12" not 13, this then allows a second "Alert" from `WKWebView` to use location data.  I could not work out how to provide a `UIAlertControl` instead of the `UIAlertView` the `WKWebView` is asking for.

There is a lot of people complaining on the web about the updates done in iOS 13, and how many frameworks and libraries have been affected by the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept alert in javascript, example how to just deny permission request:

```
 let removeLocationJS = """
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = function(success, error, options) {
     error({
         PERMISSION_DENIED: 1,
         code: 1
     });
 };
 """

 let removeLocation = WKUserScript(source: removeLocationJS, injectionTime: .atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: true)
 contentController.addUserScript(removeLocation)

 let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
 config.userContentController = contentController

 let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
```

Code snippet from @aranasaurus [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51576836/is-it-possible-to-turn-off-location-permission-in-wkwebview)

How to handle location permission instead of denied it, described [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665367/how-to-prevent-wkwebview-to-repeatedly-ask-for-permission-to-access-location)