# Repeated dialog box for permission access in Xamarin project - only in ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, prism, wkwebview

I have a Xamarin Prism Forms app that contains web page which should get the users current location.
The app already has the required "app" permissions for Android. But in ios when I call my external web page it repeatedly shows me the popup with the message :"website... Would Like To Use Your Current Location. Don't Allow / OK" each time they visit the web page from inside my Xamarin app.
I am using WkWebViewRenderer for webview.I have tried all the possible answers I got and still the problem persists.

Can anybody help me on this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution in [How to prevent WKWebView to repeatedly ask for permission to access location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665367/how-to-prevent-wkwebview-to-repeatedly-ask-for-permission-to-access-location)

The steps I followed to solve the issue are:

- Add the following code inside class definition:

  ```
  const string JavaScriptFunction = "navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = function(success, error, options) {window.webkit.messageHandlers.locationHandler.postMessage('getCurrentPosition');};";
  ```
- Add the following inside HybridWebViewRenderer constructor:

  ```
  var script = new WKUserScript(new NSString(JavaScriptFunction), 
               WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentStart, true);
  userController.AddUserScript(script);
  userController.AddScriptMessageHandler(this, "locationHandler");
  ```
- Add the following in DidReceiveScriptMessage function:

  ```
  if (message.Name == "locationHandler")
  {
    var messageBody = message.Body.ToString();
    if (messageBody == "getCurrentPosition")
    {
      CLLocationManager manager=new CLLocationManager();
      manager.RequestAlwaysAuthorization();
      manager.StartUpdatingLocation();
      ((HybridWebView)Element).EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("getLocation(\" 
      (manager.location?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0) ,\" 
      (manager.location?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0))");
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You said the popup with the message: "website... Would Like To Use Your Current Location. Don't Allow / OK", but there is not Always option in this option. You can check how your WkWebViewRenderer is to request location permissions and you can use the [requestAlwaysAuthorization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620551-requestalwaysauthorization?language=objc) method to obtain Always authorization. You also need to check whether the following keys have been added to your Info.plist file: `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`, `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`, or `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription`.

For more details, you can refer to the following documents:

[Background Location in Xamarin.iOS | Microsof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-walkthroughs/location-walkthrough)

[Requesting authorization to use location services | Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/requesting_authorization_to_use_location_services?language=objc)

Comment: Actually I am getting that option too. But the issue is after granting permission from mobile side, still two alert from website is also appearing.  I referred  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665367/how-to-prevent-wkwebview-to-repeatedly-ask-for-permission-to-access-location , but still not able to solve it. This is exactly the issue for me too.

Comment: Did the answers([Is it possible to turn off location permission in WKWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51576836/is-it-possible-to-turn-off-location-permission-in-wkwebview)) in this thread help you?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I solved it using the above link itself. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665367/how-to-prevent-wkwebview-to-repeatedly-ask-for-permission-to-access-location